# Handle java cancel button in two JOptionPane showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, sockets, joptionpane, cancel-button

First, i am sorry maybe the title is wrong. I will explain my problem. I have one joptionpane with showinputdialog component to input server address. I want after click Cancel button, it will return to main window. But in my case, it instead to second joptionpane.

My English is bad :) ... 
Anyone can help me ?

This is my code

```
    private static int setPortNumber()
{
    String portNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
            "Enter the Port number for server creation","Server Connection\n",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    int PORT = Integer.parseInt(portNumber);

    return PORT;

}   

private static String setServerName()
{   
    server_address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
            "Enter Server Address or PC-Name.", "Server Connection",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    return server_address;

}

private void networking() {
    server_address = setServerName();
        try {

            PORT = setPortNumber();
            if (server_address != null) {

                sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(server_address) ,
                        PORT);
            } 
            else {
                SocketException sc = new SocketException();
                throw sc;
            }


        // Recieving input and output streams
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        br = new BufferedReader(ir);
        pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        login.setEnabled(true);
        incoming.append("Connected to Server.please login.\n");
        connect.setEnabled(false);
        pw.println("~##~");
        pw.flush();
        login.requestFocus();
    }
```

Comment: `setServerNumber()` and `setPortNumber()` both open a `JOptionPane` and those to methods are called one after the other in your `netWorking()` method. Maybe you should change that

Comment: Sorry what should i change ? I did have to call it one by one if i click ok. But cancel button still call the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void networking() {
    server_address = setServerName();
    if(server_address == null || server_address.equals("")){
        //Handle what happens when the server name is empty (or the user clicked the cancel button. If you let the execution continue, then the try/catch block below will pop up the second jInputDialog
    }
        try {

            PORT = setPortNumber();
            if (server_address != null) {

                sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(server_address) ,
                    PORT);
            } 
            else {
                SocketException sc = new SocketException();
                throw sc;
            }
...
}
```

Comment: @user3124989 Have the method return a `boolean` and in the `if` return `false`, and at the bottom of the method return `true`

Comment: @user3124989 or simply just `return;`

Comment: @peeskillet i have try that.. and if i click cancel, it return to main window. but after click ok it also return to main window.

Comment: @user3124989 of if you need everything else executed except for the `setPortNumber();`, then if the if use `if( .. != null ..) { setPortNumber(); }`. You have options.

Comment: @user3124989 since `server_address` is already a class member, try have the `setServerName()` return `void` and then just call `setServerName()` instead of `server_name = setServerName();`

Comment: @peeskillet Ohmg.. sorry sir this is myfault. It works with your first comment here. I click ok in empty input dialog.. Thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

Run this example. It works fine

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class NetWorking {

    public static String server_address;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        networking();

    }

       private static int setPortNumber()
       {
           String portNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                   "Enter the Port number for server creation","Server Connection\n",
                   JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
           int PORT = Integer.parseInt(portNumber);

           return PORT;

       }   

       private static void setServerName()
       {   
           server_address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                   "Enter Server Address or PC-Name.", "Server Connection",
                   JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

       }

       private static void networking(){
           setServerName();
           if (server_address == null) {
               return;
           } 
            Integer  port = setPortNumber();
            if (port != null) {
                System.out.println(port);
            }
       }

}
```